# Get logical core for current thread - Measuring performance of Distributed App

Tags: java, multithreading, cpu, concurrent-programming

I am building a local distributed programs that runs locally. My computer has multiple cores, so my assumpations would be that i could achieve real paralelism for a number of threads.

Is there any way in Java to check which logical cores runs the current threads so that i can check that i have real parallelism?

Any pointers and hints would be highly apreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the info you want to see would help you ensure that you are achieving "real" parallelism.

Consider the following code :

```
public class MyClass {

    public synchronized void method1() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        MyClass c = new MyClass();
        new Thread(() -> c.method1()).start();
        new Thread(() -> c.method1()).start();
        new Thread(() -> c.method1()).start();
        new Thread(() -> c.method1()).start();
    }
}
```

Each of your thread could run on a distinct core, and the 4 execs of method1() would still be sequential.

To ensure that you will benefit from parallelism, i would rather do a cpu sampling analysis of the program (using your prefered tool. If you don't know any, jvisualvm, included in the jdk, is a good start).

For the simple program above, jvisualvm will show you that :

[image: Running threads as show by jvisualvm]

When the thread is in another color than green, it means it was blocked by something else in your program.

Here the pattern is simple. In a real world case, you might have to do cpu sampling to see what are the slowest methods, and where they are spending times.